# RaspberryPi keeps reporting error: dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'xxx' missing;

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-buster, dpkg

I have encountered a series of problems, after a week of searching and processing still have no clue.

My Pi3B+ keeps reporting errors: `"dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'xxx' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed"`, most of dpkgs are listed.
The strange thing is that almost all of the packages reporting errors are running normally.

I tried to reinstall all the packages that reported errors using `sudo aptitude reinstall xxx` . Most of the packages no longer report errors after reinstallation, but there are still some packages that cannot be installed. I tried to install them one by one manually using `sudo aptitude reinstall xxx`, and I got the following message
`docker-ce-cli is already the newest version (5:20.10.0~3-0~debian-buster)`.

The current workable solution is: `sudo apt-get remove xxx`, then `sudo aptitude install xxx` to choose to install another version and reinstall it.
**For exameple, if I use `sudo apt remove xxx', then` sudo aptitude install xxx`, it comes up` Depends: libudev1 (= 241-7~deb10u7+rpi1) but 241-7~deb10u8+rpi1 is installed`or`Depends: debconf (= 1.5.71) but 1.5.71+deb10u1 is installed`. Choose y to continue the install ,the package will be install and will not show warning again. Seems like something causes the version problem.**

But this solution has a bad effect which will cause all the previous configuration of the reinstalled package to disappear (for example, my apache after reinstallation, webdav is disabled)

Is there any solution to eliminate these errors without deleting the dpkg?

Here are some of the stupid things I've done:
It all started with a wrong python upgrade, I used `sudo apt-get remove phthon3.7` then `sudo apt-get purge python3.7`, removed python and related dependencies, and after reinstalling python3.8 (using configure, make and make install) , after this everything went wrong.

1. My openmediavault was deleted and the samba service was not working. Reinstallation keeps saying "no module named 'apt' ".
2. Reinstalled python 3.7, manually deleted some python 3.8 files, and started to get pip and python commands prompting "no such file or directory".
3. Used `export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/bin/python3` to solve the problem pip and python command problem.(Maybe, I don't really remember because I've done so many thing to deal with a bunch of problems)
4. Don't know which step of the wrong operation causes a lot of dpkg warning
5. Made a wong step and deleted /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
6. Made a wong step and deleting /var/lib/dpkg/info/

Here are some commands I have tried but won't help:

1. `sudo apt update` nothing specail happend
2. `sudo apt upgrade` nothing specail happend
3. `sudo dpkg --configure -a` nothing specail happend
4. `sudo apt install -f` return `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`
5. Make a backup for /var/lib/dpkg/info-make a new 'info' folder-`sudo apt update`- move the backup back to 'info' folder. Nothing good happened

Here are the packages that show errors：

```
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libdns1104:armhf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libx11-xcb1:armhf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'systemd-sysv' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libfluidsynth1:armhf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'psmisc' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'liblz4-1:armhf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libhogweed4:armhf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libssl1.1:armhf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libwebpdemux2:armhf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:armhf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libx11-dev:armhf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'folder2ram' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'isc-dhcp-client' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgcrypt20:armhf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'debconf-i18n' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libopenexr23:armhf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'systemd' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libnss3:armhf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libisc1100:armhf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libseccomp2:armhf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libicu63:armhf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libsystemd0:armhf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'debconf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libkrb5support0:armhf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'tzdata' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgnutls30:armhf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libuv1:armhf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libx11-data' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'docker-ce' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'debconf-utils' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libssl-dev:armhf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgssapi-krb5-2:armhf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'udev' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'containerd.io' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libwebp6:armhf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libk5crypto3:armhf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libnettle6:armhf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libisc-export1100:armhf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libudev1:armhf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'docker-ce-cli' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:armhf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libasound2:armhf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libpam-systemd:armhf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libx11-6:armhf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'phddns' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'isc-dhcp-common' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libkrb5-3:armhf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libtiff5:armhf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libsndfile1:armhf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'base-files' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libwebpmux3:armhf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libdns-export1104' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libxml2:armhf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
```

Anything else I can do to save my system?

Comment: I've tried`sudo apt --reinstall install xxx` and it return Reinstallation of docker-ce is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

The OS uses python for a number of internal tasks. If you deleted it (for whatever reason) the damage is unpredictable.

Attempting to "fix" is likely to be unproductive.

If you don't have a backup (if so WHY?) your only option is a fresh installation.

NOTE the current Bullseye "release" (it is really a beta) includes python 3.9, but introduces a number of changes, not all of which are fully operational.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've tried `sudo apt update --fix-missing` ,the hit and get goes really good just like everything works right. But when I install something, the warning show up again. The python I removed was python3.7 which was install by myself after the installation of raspbian. The native python 2.7 still hasn't been removed. I don't understand why this will cause such a  thing.

Comment: @ShakesBill Buster includes python3.7, so why you installed it is unclear. `sudo apt-get purge python3.7` would remove the system  installed version. NOTE there is no valid reason to ever use `apt-get` rather than `apt`, except in scripts

Comment: This is really great tips! I totally didn't realize that buster itself included python 3.7, I guess I should install 3.7 back and try it out. Also I always thought apt and apt-get were the same, so I was lazy and used apt, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Reinstall Python3.7 still don't solve problems. I think I need to reinstall the rest of packages manually. Now I realize the biggest mistake is uninstall the python3.7. Thanks for your help.